# Bold a string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a string and I need to add square braces and change the font to bold. Also I tried this and it doesn't wotk as expected.

```
string strID = "<b>" + strGroupID + "-</b>";
```

Now this string produces result like this `Nestle-` and the result should be like this **`[Nestle]-`**

Really appreciate any help on this.

**Code**

```
protected void gvComm_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
        {
            string strGroupID = ((DropDownList)gvComm.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlKey")).SelectedValue;
            string strComm = ((TextBox)gvComm.FooterRow.FindControl("lblOwner")).Text.Trim();
            string strLeader = ((TextBox)gvComm.FooterRow.FindControl("lblIT")).Text.Trim();
            string strName = ((TextBox)gvComm.FooterRow.FindControl("lblFTC")).Text.Trim();              
            string strID = "<b>" + strGroupID + "-</b>";
            bool success = false;
            success = InsertComm(strGroupID , strComm, strLeader, strName , strID);                
            if (success)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data Inserted Successfully');window.location='Mapping.aspx';", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Insert Operation Failed');window.location='Mapping.aspx';", true);
            }
        }
    }

public static bool InsertComm(string strGroupID , string strComm, string strLeader, string strName , string strID)
    {
        bool success = false;
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand oCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                oCommand.CommandText = "insert into Comm values ('" + strGroupID + " " + 'N/A' + "','" + strComm+ "','" + strLeader+ "','" + strName + "','" + strID+ "')";
                oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                success = true;
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

If you see strGroupID I will pass a N/A value. For Ex: The GroupID column value should be like

```
  [Nestle] - N/A where `[Nestle] -` only should be bold.
```

Comment: Where did you intend to use this code?

Comment: I am using this code to insert a field value in gridview.

Comment: You can't make a string bold. Some text displaying as bold only makes sense within the context of a specific UI. E.g. on a web page you would use HTML CSS but a label on a WPF view would be completely different. You need to give details of your UI.

Comment: May be the css applied on the gridview doesn't allow bold. There could be alot of reasons for this problem.

Comment: What is `YearComm.InsertComm`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Please take a look at my updated post.

Comment: You cant make the string itself bold but you can make its containing control render as bold e.g. with a label. 

label lblString = new Label();
lblString.text = strID;
lblString.Font = new Font(lblString.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

Comment: Still not clear how you display it.

Comment: `[GroupID] - GroupID, Value1,Value2,Value3` in this result I need to bold this value alone [GroupID] and this value comes from the string srtID. This value gets stored in a single column.

Comment: How and where is the string `Nestle-` displayed? You have to **show it bold** not to **store it bold**.

Comment: @Bharadwaj - Yes I have to show it in bold.

Comment: Yes, then how are you showing it? loading into any control like `Label`? or is it coming from database? Can you show `html`/`aspx` where `Nestle-` is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make string bold. What you can do is control you are using to display the string bold.

if this is gridview you can use the grd_RowDataBound command to make a specific cell bold e.g.
if the value you wanted to make bold existed in cell [0]:

e.Row.Cells[0].Font.Bold = true